# React Navigation pass route params after sign in with firebase

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React Native, this is my App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  

  useEffect(() => {

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
        console.log('User signed out');
      }
    })

  }, [])

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="SignUp"
          component={SignUp}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn"
          component={SignIn}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          initialParams={
            { 
              currentUser: currentUser,
              setCurrentUser: setCurrentUser
            }
          }
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is my SignIn.js component where user can enter username and password to login with firebase.

```
function SignIn({ route }) {

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser} = route.params;
 
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const userSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, username, password);
      setCurrentUser(username);
      navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
    } catch(error) {
      setCurrentUser(null);
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }


  return(
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View style={styles.page}>
        { !currentUser && 
        <>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Sign In</Text>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Username</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={(val) => setUsername(val)}
              value={username}
              autoCapitalize="none"              
            />
            <Text style={styles.label}>Password</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={(val) => setPassword(val)}
              value={password}
              secureTextEntry
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={userSignIn} style={styles.submitButton}>
              <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Sign In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Create an account</Text>
            <Button title="Sign Up" style={styles.alternativeButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')} />
          </View>
        </>
        }
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

And this is the Dashboard.js component, if user is logged in, that's the screen that the user should see

```
function Dashboard({ route }) {

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = route.params;

  const userSignOut = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut(auth);
      setCurrentUser(null);
      navigation.navigate('SignIn')
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  return(
    <View style={styles.page}>
      { currentUser &&  
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Hi, {currentUser.email}</Text> 
          <Button title="Sign Out" style={styles.heading} />
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={userSignOut} style={styles.submitButton}>
              <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>Sign Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      }
      { !currentUser &&
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <Button title="Go Back" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignIn')} />
        </View>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

On the dashboard component there is a conditional rendering based on the currentUser variable.

But currentUser is `undefined` and it's not showing the correct view.

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally render an Unauthenticated stack or an Authenticated stack. This way, you don't have to handle navigating to the right screen.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from './path-to/AuthProvider';

function App() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {!!currentUser ? <AppStackNavigator /> : <AuthStackNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

You either have a user or not, and always on the right set of screens.

Also, your login/logout logic can move to the AuthContext too.

See [Authentication in React Applications](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications)